# fuzzymatch left join for one column, but require exact matches for the rest of the columns

Tags: r, dplyr, fuzzy-search

I am trying to perform a left_join on the following two data frames:

```
df1 = data.frame(
  word = c("column", "maximum", "run", "distance", "string"),
  type = c("noun", "noun", "verb", "noin", "noun")
)

df2 = data.frame(
  word = c("col", "maximim", "rim", "distance", "string"),
  type = c("noun", "noun", "verb", "noun", "noun"),
  metadata = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2)
)

fuzzyjoin::stringdist_left_join(df1, df2, by = c("word", "type"), method = "hamming", max_dist = 1)
```

This allows a fuzzy match for columns "word" and "type", allowing up to one substitution for a match. However, I want to allow for one substitution on only the "word" column, and require an exact match for the "type" column.

Perhaps another, more general way, to ask the question is how one can set different distance thresholds for different columns that a join is being performed on.

In the case that some columns are required exact matches, it is more efficient to just require this, than to compute distance and threshold at distance of 0, however.

What would be the most efficient way to allow fuzzy matches on only a single column, and exact matches on the rest?

What about the best way to allow fuzzy matches, at different thresholds for each column? As a bonus, what about allowing different thresholds on some columns, as well as requiring an exact match for a different set of columns?

Thanks,
Jack